# al redirigir con modal de Bootstrap, el fondo queda grisáceo

Tags: bootstrap

Buen día. Estoy utilizando VUE + Bootstrap. En una parte de la página, estoy utilizando un modal que posee un botón que redirige a otra URL del sitio, sin embargo, la pantalla queda oscura cuando ya es redirigido.

```
            <!-- Button-Modal -->
        <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
        >
            Carrito
        </button>
        <!-- Button-Modal -->
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div
            class="modal fade"
            id="exampleModal"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true"
        >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                            Contenido del carrito
                        </h5>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            class="btn-close"
                            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close"
                        ></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div>
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <router-link
                            exact-active-class="active"
                            to="/home"
                            class="btn btn-info"
                            >Más detalles</router-link
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
```

Para que se hagan a una idea (y a continuación también adjuntaré una foto de cómo queda), cuando se abre el modal el fondo queda grisáceo; una vez que doy clic en el botón dentro del modal, toda la pantalla queda opaca.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que luego de redirigir la pantalla no quede oscura?

Comment: Sugerencia de título, para que sea más descriptivo: _al abrir modal de Bootstrap, el fondo queda grisáceo_. ¿Te fijaste si tenés errores en consola?

Comment: @padaleiana hola, cómo estás? El modal sirve correctamente, el problema viene cuando le doy clic a un botón que tengo (en el modal-footer) que me redirige a otro sitio de la página.

Comment: ¿El comportamiento es el mismo en otros navegadores? ¿Podrías especificar también en la pregunta qué versiones de vue (y vue-router, asumo) y bootstrap estás utilizando?

Comment: En mis pruebas parece funcionar bien, pero he sustituido el `<router-link>` por una `<a>`... lo que si veo raro es que el cierre del `</router-link` queda una linea por debajo... prueba de ponerlo todo en una linea a ver si es eso

Comment: Lo que yo veo por el código y la imagen, que todo parece funcionar correctamente. De hecho estas parado en la ruta ``home``. El problema que se ve, es que queda un overlay propio de un modal que no se cerró. Para mi la solución sería reemplazar el ``router link`` por ``button`` y el ``to`` por ``@click="redirigirHome()"``, y en el objeto ``methods`` declarar la función ``redirigirHome`` que primero cierre el modal (según qué versión de boostrap uses tendrás que buscar el método), y luego redirija a home por medio de ``this.$route.push({path: '/home'})`` (vue 2).

Comment: en vue 3 deberias importar useRouter, crear ``const router = useRouter()`` y luego en el método ``redirigiriHome`` luego de cerrar el modal deberias hacer ``router.push({path: '/home'})``

Comment: Recomiendo hacer todas las redirecciones dentro del sitio por medio de ``router``, evitar usar <a></a> o redirecciones por medio de javascript. Redireccionar de esa manera recarga el sitio, y la idea de los frameworks reactivos es que todo se mantenga en memoria sin necesidad de recargar el sitio completo.